# Why does the right side of frame keep flashing?

Tags: graphics, manipulate

**What does this flashing mean?**

I found at the same time Mathematica was consuming a lot of CPU power.

[image]

**1st input**

```
 Manipulate[b = 2 r + 1;
 Show[p1 = 
   ContourPlot[{x^2 + (y - r)^2 == r^2, x/12 + y/b == 1}, {x, -20, 
     20}, {y, -20, 20}, Axes -> True, Frame -> False, 
    AspectRatio -> 1, PerformanceGoal -> "Goal"],
  Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Red, 
    Point@Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[p1]}]], {{r, 4, 
   "Radius"}, -10, 10, 0.01}]
```

**2nd input:**

```
Manipulate[b = 2 r + 1;
 Show[Evaluate[{p1 = 
     ContourPlot[x^2 + (y - r)^2 == r^2, {x, -20, 20}, {y, -20, 20}, 
      Axes -> True, Frame -> False, AspectRatio -> 1, 
      PerformanceGoal -> "Goal"], 
    p2 = ContourPlot[x/12 + y/b == 1, {x, -20, 20}, {y, -20, 20}, 
      Axes -> True, Frame -> False, AspectRatio -> 1],
    Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Red, 
      Point@Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections@Show[p1, p2]}]
    }]],
 {{r, 4}, -10, 10, 0.01}]
```

Comment: This happens when two (or more) dynamic evaluations (like `Manipulate` keep working simultaneously. Check, if this is the case. If yes, to avoid this you may scroll the page such that the previous dynamic evaluation is not visible (above the frame of the screen). In this case it stops being evaluated. Another possibility is that you get two or more usual (non-dynamic) evaluation running. I think it is better to avoid such parallel evaluations. Make "Alt+." (that is, Alt and point) to abort, and start one evaluation at a time.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch    I did have a previous dynamic evaluation working before this.

Comment: A common cause is that each is updating the same global variable, triggering an update in the other.  Can't tell without the code, though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by @MichaelE2 in the comments, both your plots access the same global variables `b` and `p1`, causing the manipulates to update each other. You can localize the variables to the manipulate by adding a variable specification of the form `{name, None}` (the `None` prevents any control from being generated):

```
Manipulate[b = 2 r + 1;
 Show[p1 = 
   ContourPlot[{x^2 + (y - r)^2 == r^2, x/12 + y/b == 1}, {x, -20, 
     20}, {y, -20, 20}, Axes -> True, Frame -> False, 
    AspectRatio -> 1, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], 
  Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Red, 
    Point@Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[p1]}]], {{r, 4, 
   "Radius"}, -10, 10, 0.01}, {b, None}, {p1, None}]

Manipulate[b = 2 r + 1;
 Show[{p1 = 
    ContourPlot[x^2 + (y - r)^2 == r^2, {x, -20, 20}, {y, -20, 20}, 
     Axes -> True, Frame -> False, AspectRatio -> 1, 
     PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], 
   p2 = ContourPlot[x/12 + y/b == 1, {x, -20, 20}, {y, -20, 20}, 
     Axes -> True, Frame -> False, AspectRatio -> 1], 
   Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Red, 
     Point@Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections@Show[p1, p2]}]}], {{r, 
   4}, -10, 10, 0.01}, {b, None}, {p1, None}, {p2, None}]
```